# Laravel form request passedValidation() and $request->validated()

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

I 'm trying to implement a cast method in a formRequest just after validation, using passedValidation() function.

Everything looks good but the cast made in  passedValidation()  don't appear in $request->validated(), but is visible in $request->all().

## My form request

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Requests\Models\Company;
    
    use App\Http\Requests\CustomFormRequest;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Propaganistas\LaravelPhone\PhoneNumber;
    

    class CompanyFormRequest extends CustomFormRequest
    {
 
        protected function prepareForValidation()
        {
            $this->merge([
                             'is_presting' => !$this->missing('is_presting') 
                                             && $this->input('is_presting'),
                         ]);
        }
    
        public function rules () : array
        {
           
            
            return [
                'name' => [ 'required' , 'string' ] ,
                'street' => [ 'string' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'city' => [ 'string' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'post_code' => [ 'string' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'TVA' => [ 'string' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'language' => [ 'required' , 'string' ] ,
                'bank' => [ 'string' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'email' => [ 'string' , 'email' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'website' => [ 'string' , 'url' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'latitude' => [ 'numeric' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'longitude' => [ 'numeric' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'reference' => [ 'string' , 'nullable' ] ,
                'is_presting' => [ 'boolean' ] ,
                'phone_country' => [ 'required_with:phone_field' , 'string' ] ,
                'phone_field' => [ 'required_with:phone_country' , 'phone:'.$this->input('phone_country') ] ,
            
            ];
        }
        
        public function authorize () : bool
        {
            return app () -> runningInConsole () 
                || ( Auth ::check () && Auth ::user () -> can ( 'manage_content' ) );
        }
    
        protected function passedValidation ()
        {
           $this->merge( [
                             'phone_field' => 
                                 (string) PhoneNumber ::make ( $this -> input ( 'phone_field' ) , 
                                                               $this -> input ( 'phone_country' ) )
                         ]);
        }
    
    }
```

## $request->all() before validation

```
array:16 [▼
  "name" => "De Greef SCA"
  "street" => "chemin Gérard 527"
  "city" => "Tournai"
  "post_code" => "6485"
  "TVA" => "BE0958232035"
  "language" => "fr_FR"
  "bank" => "BE96227410211607"
  "phone_field" => "0471321102"
  "phone_country" => "BE"
  "email" => "jpauwels@example.org"
  "website" => "http://devos.org/ab-et-itaque-a.html"
  "latitude" => -64.420589
  "longitude" => 65.667543
  "reference" => "OMZ"
  "active" => true
  "is_presting" => true
]
```

## $request->validated() after validation

```
array:16 [▼
  "name" => "De Greef SCA"
  "street" => "chemin Gérard 527"
  "city" => "Tournai"
  "post_code" => "6485"
  "TVA" => "BE0958232035"
  "language" => "fr_FR"
  "bank" => "BE96227410211607"
  "phone_field" => "0471321102"
  "phone_country" => "BE"
  "email" => "jpauwels@example.org"
  "website" => "http://devos.org/ab-et-itaque-a.html"
  "latitude" => -64.420589
  "longitude" => 65.667543
  "reference" => "OMZ"
  "active" => true
  "is_presting" => true
]
```

## $request->all() after validation

```
array:16 [▼
  "name" => "De Greef SCA"
  "street" => "chemin Gérard 527"
  "city" => "Tournai"
  "post_code" => "6485"
  "TVA" => "BE0958232035"
  "language" => "fr_FR"
  "bank" => "BE96227410211607"
  "phone_field" => "+32471321102"
  "phone_country" => "BE"
  "email" => "jpauwels@example.org"
  "website" => "http://devos.org/ab-et-itaque-a.html"
  "latitude" => -64.420589
  "longitude" => 65.667543
  "reference" => "OMZ"
  "active" => true
  "is_presting" => true
]
```

#### We see in $request->all() after the validation that the cast is well executed on 'phone_field' but why doesn't it appear in $request->validated() ???

thanks.

Comment: I think it is simply because it isn't validated, remove the complex validation from the 'phone_field' and then check to see if it appears on $request->validated()

[ 'required_with:phone_country' , 'phone:'.$this->input('phone_country') ]
This is way too complex to understand what is happening. just change it to 'required ' for debugging purposes, see if it works, if it does then your issue is with validation.
Also you might get more answers if you simplify your question instead of dumping the whole class :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's validated because I pass the validation and the passedValidation() function is process. I see the cast in $request->all() in the controller. My question is why in $request->all() and not in $request->validated()

Answer (score 1):

It is because `$request->all()` & `$request->validated()` have different implementation on different classes. You can see it in [FormRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php) source code. In short:

- `$request->all()` take input in the $request as it present on function call
- on the other hand, `$request->validated()` was actually calling `validated()` function on underlying Validator object. If you trace it, all the inputs was passed when FormRequest was [creating Validator object](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L110). Hence, anything you do with $request input in `passedValidation()` did not affect input that was already passed to Validator object.

I hope my explanation is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you probably need to merge with the validated data. If you are on recent version of Laravel you can use the `safe()` method

```php
$validated = $request->safe()->merge([
    'phone_field' => (string) PhoneNumber::make ( 
        $this->input('phone_field'), $this->input('phone_country') 
    )
)];
```

If you want the FormRequest class to encapsulate the merging, you can define a custom method say `validatedWithCasts` and then use this method in the controller or where ever else

```php
class CompanyFormRequest extends CustomFormRequest
{
 
    // ...other methods and rules
    
    public function validatedWithCasts ()
    {
        return $this->safe()->merge([
            'phone_field' => (string) PhoneNumber::make ( 
                $this->input('phone_field'), $this->input('phone_country') 
            )

        ]);
    }
    
}
```

Then in controller you can use it like

```php
$request->validatedWithCasts();
```